# using D_ptr implementation destructor

Tags: c++, qt, pimpl-idiom

I tried implementing PIMPL method of using D_ptr in Qt widget.

The following code is what I implemented.

```
class GuiCentralHandler : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GuiCentralHandler (QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GuiCentralHandler ();

protected:
    GuiCentralHandlerPrivate * const d_ptr;

private: //class methods
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(GuiCentralHandler )
};

GuiCentralHandler ::GuiCentralHandler (QWidget *parent)
    :QWidget(parent),d_ptr(new GuiCentralHandlerPrivate (this))
{
}

GuiCentralHandler ::~GuiCentralHandler ()
{
    Q_D(GuiCentralHandler );
    delete &d_ptr;
}
```

and my private d_ptr is

```
class GuiCentralHandlerPrivate 
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(GuiCentralHandlerPrivate )
public:
     GuiCentralHandlerPrivate (GuiCentralHandler *parent);

protected:
    GuiCentralHandler * const q_ptr;
};

GuiCentralHandlerPrivate ::GuiCentralHandlerPrivate (GuiCentralHandler *parent)
    : q_ptr(parent)
{
}
```

But when i call the destructor of `GuiCentralHandler ::~GuiCentralHandler ()`
it is crashing. How i can delete the `d_ptr` or d_func from the main widget. 
Please point out where I'm going wrong with this implementation.

Comment: You are setting parent to `GuiCentralHandlerPrivate` and then you delete it explicitly. This deletes the object twice and thus crashes.

Comment: Try to replace `delete &d_ptr;` with `delete d_ptr;`

Comment: @jaac thanks for the reply . i tried that too. when i removed the destructor delete in GuiCentralHandler ::~GuiCentralHandler () but it is not calling the  destructor of  private class csGuiCentralModuleHandlerPrivate::~csGuiCentralModuleHandlerPrivate() 
{
    qDebug()<<"csGuiCentralModuleHandlerPrivate::~csGuiCentralModuleHandlerPrivate()";
}

Comment: @andrii thanks andrill , yes i tried that too .

Comment: @Jaa-c, `GuiCentralHandlerPrivate` it's not derived from `QObject`, so `parent` in its constructor is not a `parent` object in terms of Qt and woun't be deleted automatically

Comment: @ andrii , yes andrii your comment is right .. please post as a reply i will mark the answer . it was my mistake. i not define destructor for GuiCentralHandlerPrivate. so when i call delete d_ptr it is crashing . so when i defined it , calling delete d_ptr instead of delete &d_ptr is working . thanks once more .

Comment: @Andrii: true, I just took a quick look on the code and didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a pointer to the [operator delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/) instead of the adress of the pointer:

```
delete d_ptr;
```

Instead of:

```
delete &d_ptr;
```

[Here](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer), you can find information about d-pointer